# LINQ-to-SQL does not retrieve the latest (updated) version stored in the database

Tags: asp.net, database, linq-to-sql, sql-server-express, updates

When using a linqdatasource to update my sqlexpress database everything is displayed ok, but when I try retrieving the contents manually using:

```
public static IQueryable<MarkingScheme> listMarkingSchemes(string moduleID, string academicYear)
{
    return
        from m in feedbackDB.MarkingSchemes
        where m.moduleID == moduleID && m.academicYear == academicYear
        orderby m.schemeID descending
        select m;
}
```

I get back a previous version of the data!! weirdly though, when I retrieve only specific parts of the same table, using:

```
public static IQueryable listNames(string moduleID, string academicYear)
{
    return
        from m in feedbackDB.MarkingSchemes
        where m.moduleID == moduleID && m.academicYear == academicYear
        orderby m.schemeID descending
        select new { m.schemeID, m.assignmentName };
}
```

I get back the updated version!!!
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how I can always get the latest version of the data when doing manual queries? I've tried setting the 'update check' option in the dataclasses.dbml file to either 'Always' and 'WhenChanged', but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: Is SubmitChanges getting called in every path?  LINQ delivers rows from the DataContext object's cache.  So if SubmitChanges is not called in every scenario where a change occurs, you would get the original data, not the modified data as you expect.

Comment: the content is updated through the linqdatasource, so I'm assuming so! and isn't it strange that the selective query 'select new { m.schemeID, m.assignmentName }' sees the update, whereas using simply 'select m' doesn't??

Comment: the updated content does seem to show up after a while, or when I update the datacontext... but the 'delay loaded' option is set to false...

Comment: Hmmm...I wonder if it's a lazy loading issue then?  If you ToList the result of the first method, does it show the changes?

Comment: I'd tried getting it back as Array(), and tried it now as List(), but I'm still not getting the updated content..

Comment: How are you defining your update?  Are you assigning it a command, using autoupdate or handling events?

Comment: the update is done by the linqdatasource, so I'm assuming autoupdate? I can see the change being made in the db, but it is not returned when I use the 'select m' query...

Comment: @Josh i seem to be making some progress.. if I do an update manually using `var product = (from p in feedbackDB.MarkingSchemes
                       where p.schemeID == schemeID
                       select p).Single();

        product.assignmentName = newName;
        feedbackDB.SubmitChanges();` then the changes are shown immediately in my application. So I'm guessing the culprit is the linqdatasource, maybe not notifying (or delaying the notification of) the datacontext that the data have been updated?

Comment: Definitely check and ensure the AutoUpdate property is set to True.  Also, if it is, make sure you do not have a Select query assigned to the LinqDataSource.  If you do, I believe that automatically disables autoupdate.

Comment: @Josh yes, the linqdatasource does a select as well! it doesn't have an autoupdate property that I can set though, is there something we can do to fix it??

Comment: Post how your LinqDataSource is being created...

Comment: `    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" OrderBy="lastModified desc" TableName="MarkingSchemes" Where="schemeID == @schemeID">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="schemeID" QueryStringField="scheme" Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>`

Comment: @Josh but why does the linqdatasource's select statement retrieve the latest version of the data, and the manual one doesn't?

Comment: I'm thinking the LinqDataSource is caching and it's sending you the result from the cache rather than the database.  This was proven by you SubmittingChanges and it working afterward.  I haven't used a LinqDataSource in a year so I'm trying to remember any gotchas with it.

Comment: @Josh you mean like lazy loading? but that's disabled in the datacontext... and I can visually verify that the data updated by the linqdatasource have been changed correctly in the database...

Comment: LINQ itself caches data even when you write to the database through it using an direct UPDATE statement.  It's not lazy loading it's just how the guts work.  There are multiple states in a LINQ datacontext which rely on SubmitChanges.  For example, when you start everything is unmodified.  Then when you change something those changes are tracked but LINQ will return you the original data not the modified data until you SubmitChanges.

Comment: You may have stumbled onto something or the LinqDataSource is being used in a way Microsoft would consider unsupported.  I think your best solution is to handle the insert, update, and delete events of the LinqDataSource and call SubmitChanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work, I had to manually set the Auto-Sync method to 'Always' for all affected columns in the datacontext!

Thanks again to @Josh for all his help, really appreciated!!